# set a variable as json key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I wish to use a variable as json key in javascript

`var chtid = "1234"
firebase.database().ref().set ({chtid :"hi"});`

where `chtid` would be a variable

I tried this way but to no success

`var chtid = "1234"
firebase.database().ref().set ({[chtid] :"hi"});`

Any simple soulution please.

Comment: What does "no success" mean? Did you get the wrong result? Did you get an error message?

Comment: do you want to use chtid as a value? then `{chtid:chtid}` will be right. But if this is what you want, I recommend you to change variable name. :)

Comment: @CanetRobern — The question is quite clear that they want the key to be the value of the chtid variable.

Comment: @Quentin I am getting `chtid` as a key in firebase instead of 1234

Comment: @sam — When you use `{[chtid] :"hi"}`?

Comment: Its the same as `chtid` producing same results

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem — http://jsbin.com/facajusawi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Quentin oh.. sorry. forgive my misunderstanding..

Comment: sorry its giving syntax error `firebase.database().ref().set ({[chtid] :[{usr : $scope.usrid, msg : $scope.chatmsg.msg, time : dte }]});` ERROR is `I/chromium(10204): [INFO:CONSOLE(421)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js (421)
`

Comment: Whatever you are using to execute the JS doesn't support a new enough version of JS to support that feature. Either get a transpiler or use one of the alternative approaches on the duplicate question.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: bhosdi walo madar chod jab answer nahi kar pa rahe to maa ku chudwa rahe downvote kar k

Answer (score 0):

Put it on a variable first:

```
var obj = {};
var chtid = "1234"
obj[chtid] = "Hi";
firebase.database().ref().set (obj);
```

hope that helps